# Grails values from large collection not saving

Tags: grails, collections, limit

I seem to somehow be loosing values of inputs somewhere between the GSP page and the controller.

I have a REPORT object, which has a large number of COUNT objects, which displays as tabular data through some looping in the GSP. Because there is quite a bit of nested looping, the formula for determining the instance number 'i' of each COUNT is complicated, but if I output it to screen, it is correct (counts from 0 - 419 with no issue).

What all this means is I have ONE block of code which creates the input field for each of the COUNT instances, so the code is exactly the same, and each one is named counts[0].total through to counts[419].total as you would expect (there are other hidden values to determine which column and row each COUNT sits in as well, but this is still all being output by the same single block of code iterated 420 times) BUT, somewhere along the line, SOME of these values are being lost - about 70% of the values persist to the DB on save, but the other 30% or so disappear and remain as 0.

There is no pattern to which ones save and which don't, though it is always the same values that don't work. I have two reports doing this that use the same code (though the report is different) and I have one report which does this perfectly...

**I have managed to work out this much**

SOMETHING In grails is limiting the set size to 256 - It will not allow me to save more than 256 objects at once, but I cannot work out how to override this.

if it's not within grails, could it be a limit to the HTTP post method?

Any help someone please? I am rapidly running out of hair.

Comment: Please provide a sample code to help us solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The limit to `GET` and `POST` request data size is both limited from client side and server side.

In **Grails**:
The default value is 2 MB (refer `maxPostSize` attribute of the `<Connector>` in `server.xml`.)

And if this size exceeded:
HTTP 1.1 returns Status Code `414` *Request-URI Too Long* for the cases where a server-defined limit is reached.

*But older browsers limit the size of `GET` request to 255 bytes* ( so check your are not using the `GET` request).